# How can I use multiple .env files for the same environment in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I work on an application where our database administrator has mandated that the production database credentials be inaccessible to anyone that's not a database admin or the web app itself. He suggested we create a second .env file that contains only the database credentials so that he can lock down that file. Is there a way to do this? Essentially we would be reading config values from both .env files.

For example our app config file might look like

```
return [
    'some_configuration' => env1('SOME_CONFIGURATION'),
]
```

While the database config file might look like

```
return [
    'database_password' => env2('DB_PASSWORD')
]
```

How can I read configs from multiple .env files like this?

Comment: Do you not just have a local database for development?

Comment: It was removed in Laravel 5. You can access similar behavior with an external package, like https://github.com/phanan/cascading-config. Alternatively, you can roll your own with something like `parse_ini_file` and `array_merge`.

Comment: You could grab the password from an arbitrary file via `file_get_contents`, i.e. `'database_password' => file_get_contents('.secret_file')`, but I'm dubious of the value here. If it's available to the web app, it's available to a developer via `php artisan tinker` or just dumping it out in a secret route or something.

Comment: @ceejayoz The arbitrary file looks like the way I have to go. And yes it can probably be circumvented but from my understanding it's less to protect it from the actual developers, but rather provide protection in the case of a unattended terminal or a theft of a developers server access credentials. If you post your comment as an answer I can mark it as correct since it resolves my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet will probably be using an arbitrary file and getting its contents via `file_get_contents`:

```
return [
    'database_password' => trim(file_get_contents('.secret_file'))
]
```

(The `trim` is in case your database administrator leaves a stray `\n` or space or something.)